# simplify expression with indices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following expression:

${{{x^{2\over3}} + {x^{3\over4}} + 2}\over x^4}$

I can split this out to:

${{{{x^{2\over3}}\over x^4}} + {{x^{3\over4}}\over x^4} + {2\over x^4}}$

I can then divide the numerator by the denominator to give:

${x^{-10\over3} + x^{-13\over4} +  ???}$

I don't understand what to do with the last term, i.e. ${2\over x^4}$

The answer the textbook gives is:

${x^{-10\over3} + x^{-13\over4} +  2x^{-4}}$

So I am not sure how the last term was arrived at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very definition of $x^{-4}$ is $\dfrac{1}{x^4}$. So $\dfrac2{x^4}=2\times\dfrac{1}{x^4}=2x^{-4}$.

Another way to see this is $2=2x^0$ so

$$\dfrac2{x^4}=\dfrac{2x^0}{x^4}=2x^{0-4}=2x^{-4}$$

you are doing the same thing with the others :

$$\dfrac{x^{\frac23}}{x^4}=x^{\frac23}\times x^{-4}=x^{\frac23-4}=x^{-\frac{10}3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$2 = 2 x^0$
And hence $\frac{2}{x^4} = \frac{2x^0}{x^4} = 2x^{-4} $ .
Hope that helps.